# Gremlin: How to traverse backward and/or forward based on a vertex id

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

***Usecase***: Given a person (with a known id), find that person's all ancestors and all descendants.

***Example***:
**Vertex**:
Person1 (id=**11**) -> Person2 (id=**22**) -> Person3 (id=**33**) -> Person4 (id=**44**) -> Person5 (id=**55**)
**Edge**:
Every vertex can have almost two edges denoting the relationship:
Person1 (***isParentOf***) -> Person2 (***isParentOf***) -> Person3 (***isParentOf***) -> Person4 (***isParentOf***) -> Person5
Person1 <- (***isChildOf***) Person2 <- (***isChildOf***) Person3 <- (***isChildOf***) Person4 <- (***isChildOf***) Person5

- ***E.g. Query 1***:
  Given Person1 (id=**11**), find Person1's all ancestors and all descendants.
  *Expected response*: [***isParentOf***: **22** (Person2), **33** (Person3), **44** (Person4), **55** (Person(5)]
- ***E.g. Query 2***:
  Given Person3 (id=**33**), find Person3's all ancestors and all descendants.
  *Expected response*: [***isChildOf***: **22** (Person2), **11** (Person1), ***isParentOf***: **44** (Person4), **55** (Person5)]
- ***E.g. Query 3***:
  Given Person5 (id=**55**), find Person5's all ancestors and all descendants.
  *Expected response*: [***isChildOf***: **44** (Person4), **33** (Person3), **22** (Person2), **11** (Person1)]

The response should keep the order of the ancestors and all descendants to help with other follow-up queries. The response should also contain the name property of the persons.

Test data populated at https://gremlify.com/pk9z0s6gv4g/5

```
g.addV('PERSON').property(id, '11').
  property('name', 'person1').as('p1').
  addV('PERSON').property(id, '22').
  property('name', 'person2').as('p2').
  addV('PERSON').property(id, '33').
  property('name', 'person3').as('p3').
  addV('PERSON').property(id, '44').
  property('name', 'person4').as('p4').
  addV('PERSON').property(id, '55').
  property('name', 'person5').as('p5').
  addE('isChildOf').from('p2').to('p1').
  addE('isParentOf').from('p1').to('p2').
  addE('isChildOf').from('p3').to('p2').
  addE('isParentOf').from('p2').to('p3').
  addE('isChildOf').from('p4').to('p3').
  addE('isParentOf').from('p3').to('p4').
  addE('isChildOf').from('p5').to('p4').
  addE('isParentOf').from('p4').to('p5')
```

I tried the following example query:

```
g.V('33').repeat(out('isParentOf')).times(2).path()
```

Response

```
path[v[33], v[44], v[55]
```

My query has the following issues:

1. Only can check for 'isParentOf' or 'isChildOf' and not both.
2. Query search is limited to the times(2) parameter. I want to search for all ancestors and all descendants.
3. It is return only the IDs and not the properties of the Person (like the name).

With my limited understanding of GraphDB and all the examples I have seen, the query must contain a limiting id and/or source+destination nodes (vertex) to traverse. I have not seen an open-ended query that traverses from a source node to a leaf node and vice-versa.

Comment: Just a quick comment. When you find yourself needing to search in two directions from a given start, often a `union` of the `out` and `in` paths will suffice. Using `project` may also be an option. When I get a little more time I will try to write up a tested answer (or someone else may get to it first!) Thanks for providing a question that includes a sample graph. That helps a lot when testing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Gremlin Console, here is an example that uses a `union` step to search for both children and parents. I am a little curious why you modeled these both as outgoing relationships. If you modeled one as incoming and the other as outgoing, you could just have `isParentOf` edges, and depending on the direction you travel (in or out), you could infer if someone is a child or a parent. Anyway, using the sample data:

```java
gremlin> g.V('33').
......1>   union(repeat(out('isChildOf')).until(__.not(out('isChildOf'))),
......2>         repeat(out('isParentOf')).until(__.not(out('isParentOf')))).
......3>   path().
......4>     by('name')  

==>[person3,person2,person1]
==>[person3,person4,person5]
```

Changing the query a bit, we can annotate the results to show the relationship type:

```java
gremlin> g.V('33').
......1>   union(project('child-of').by(repeat(out('isChildOf')).until(__.not(out('isChildOf'))).path().by('name')),
......2>         project('parent-of').by(repeat(out('isParentOf')).until(__.not(out('isParentOf'))).path().by('name'))) 
   
==>[child-of:[person3,person2,person1]]
==>[parent-of:[person3,person4,person5]]
```

Pretty printed the query looks like this:

```java
g.V('33').
  union(
    project('child-of').
      by(
        repeat(out('isChildOf')).until(__.not(out('isChildOf'))).
        path().by('name')),
    project('parent-of').
      by(
        repeat(out('isParentOf')).until(__.not(out('isParentOf'))).
        path().by('name')))
```

Finally, if you do not want the starting person to appear in the results:

```java
gremlin> g.V('33').
......1>   union(
......2>     project('child-of').
......3>       by(
......4>         repeat(out('isChildOf')).until(__.not(out('isChildOf'))).
......5>         path().by('name').range(local,1,-1)),
......6>     project('parent-of').
......7>       by(
......8>         repeat(out('isParentOf')).until(__.not(out('isParentOf'))).
......9>         path().by('name').range(local,1,-1))) 

==>[child-of:[person2,person1]]
==>[parent-of:[person4,person5]]
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. Regarding your note, isn't one relationship outgoing (`isChildOf`) and the other incoming (`isParentOf`)? And also, are you suggesting that the same query output can be achieved with only one edge (`isParentOf`) between the vertices instead of two?

Comment: You could model this as "isParentOf" going out to the children of V('33') and the parents of V('33') coming in also using "isParentOf". Then the query would be out('isParentOf') and in('isParentOf') - this is by no means the only way to model this but it more closely models a "family tree" type of structure perhaps.

Comment: I was mainly thinking that it's possible to avoid having the duplicate edges.

Comment: Okie, that makes sense. Thanks for the improvement suggestion.